# Content Security Policy violation

Tags: html, http, https, content-security-policy

On my page I have given hierarchy:

```
Page - http://179.15.31.103/path

|- frame - //proxy.domain.training/path 

    |- frame - https://app.domain.training/path
```

And inner frame comes with given header

```
Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors app.domain.training proxy.domain.training domain.training *.domain.training 179.15.31.103
```

Looks like all is correct, but I got such error in chrome (error in ff too):

> Refused to display 'https://app.domain.training/path' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors app.domain.training proxy.domain.training domain.training *.domain.training 179.15.31.103".

I think that it could be becouse of https but I can not check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest prepending the URL scheme(s) to the domains in your `Content-Security-Policy` header. You may end up having to specify the domain twice to cover both `http` and `https`, but it does seem to solve the problem.

I faced a similar problem; if the parent page was served over plain `http` and the iframed page served the CSP header with the parent domain included but without the URL scheme, both Firefox and Chrome would give the error you quoted.

The biggest clue I found as to why this occurs is in Pale Moon's (a Firefox fork) release notes:

> 26.5.0 (2016-09-28) Fixes/Changes:
>
> Implemented a breaking CSP (content security policy) spec change; when a page with CSP is loaded over http, Pale Moon now interprets CSP
>   directives to also include https versions of the hosts listed in CSP
>   if a scheme (http/https) isn't explicitly listed. This breaks with CSP
>   1.0 which is more restrictive and doesn't allow this cross-protocol access, but is in line with CSP 2 where this is allowed.

https://www.palemoon.org/releasenotes-archived.shtml

However, it seems that Pale Moon 26.5.0 still behaves similarly to Firefox and Chrome.

Scott Helme also blogged about a [similar issue](https://scotthelme.co.uk/safari-doesnt-like-csp/) with Safari, but it sounds like this is now resolved.

One other thing to watch out for is if the framed page also serves `X-Frame-Options` header. I believe Firefox and Safari are the only browsers that support both this header and CSP's `frame-ancestors` header, and certainly in Firefox's case `X-Frame-Options` does seem to take precedence. And with `X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM` you are only allowed to specify one URI, so you may have to look at varying the headers for different browsers depending on your needs.

Comment: Yep, that looks right. In my case that error was fixed by adding both _http_ and _https_ protocols to CSP header explicitly.